# jquery chain in div overlay

Tags: jquery, chaining

I'm trying to 'chain in' (add) and additional function to this:

Original Code, it activates the ScrollTo plugin:

```
$('a.scroll').live('click',function(){   
   $.scrollTo(this.hash+"_", 3333, {easing:'easeOutCubic'} ); 
   window.location.hash = this.hash;
   return false;
});
```

What I want is, while the page is smooth-scrolling, to ALSO have a div overlay fadeIn, stay on the screen for a couple seconds, and then fadeOut and remove itself just before the smooth-scrolling ends.

I'm already using this div overlay called #preloader on normal page loads, but I'd like to also use it during the scrollTo action. (It's a fixed overlay div with a css3 "loading" animation inside it.)

Here's an example of what I've tried so far, to try and "chain" this in:

```
$('a.scroll').live('click',function(){   
    $.scrollTo(this.hash+"_", 3333, {easing:'easeOutCubic'} ); 
        $('#preloader').fadeIn(1234,function(){  // overlay div
            $(this).delay(1234).remove(); 
        });
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    return false;
});
```

With this, nothing happens. ScrollTo still works, but the overlay doesn't appear.

How do I chain this in the correct way? It needs to fadeIn, then after a set delay, fadeOut. Thanks for your help I'm pretty useless with jquery.

Comment: is there any important reason for giving up readability in your code?

Comment: I don't understand the question..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working so I ended up going with a different effect:

```
$('a.scroll').live('click',function(){  
    $('body').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    $.scrollTo(this.hash+"_", 3333, {easing:'easeInOutExpo'}); 
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('body').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    return false;
});
```

ScrollTo feels a lot smoother (less jumpy or unsmooth) using this. Before the smooth-scrolling happens, the body opacity shrinks down to 0.3, and then once the scrollTo animation is complete, the page content fades back in to regular 1.0 opacity.

It's not what I originally wanted, but it does the job of giving the illusion of more smoothness when using scrollTo.